# Enabled a disabled button from a popup alert

Tags: javascript

I have a program that once it detects a certain condition it disabled the submit button. To enable it the user must click a button that shows a popup using Javascript's alert.

Upon success of that transaction I close the alert window. But found out I cannot enabled the button I disabled.

Any idea how?

This is my code to disabled the button upon detection of condition:

```
 <script>
  document.getElementById("btnLog").disabled = true;
 </script>
```

Then upon success of the process in the popup window I use this:

```
echo "<script> document.getElementById('btnLog').disabled = false; </script>";
echo "<script> window.close(); </script>";
```

Comment: What kind of modal window do you use? Modal with Iframe or browser pop-up window?

Comment: Just a simple alert. window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=700,height=350,directories=no,location=no');

Comment: I'm just guessing here since it's hard to tell without a working example, but could it be that the code to re-enable the button is executed in the new window you opened? If so, the button you are looking for will not be part of that window's DOM, so you can't address it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('btnLog').disabled = false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mfqywuts/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.